# How to use credentials with slackSend

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

So I'm trying to use slackSend in my Jenkinsfile to post build status on a channel and I'm trying to explicitly define everything like this- (for some reason I have to define it like this)

```
WithCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'theSlackToken', variable: 'slackCredentials')]) {
    slackSend (channel: '@johnsmith', message: 'hello there', color: '#3eb991', failOnError: true, teamDomain: 'myteamsubdomain', token: slackCredentials)
}
```

But when I use these above lines in my Jenkinsfile I get error saying no such DSL method string.

Please help I will highly appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Have you verified you have properly installed the [Credentials Binding Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/credentials-binding/)?

Answer (score 3):

There's a few issues here:

1. First for your command to work, you shouldn't use 'withCredentials', only thing you need is the credentialsId, and then set it as tokenCredentialId, like this:
   `slackSend (channel: '@johnsmith', message: 'hello there', color: '#3eb991', tokenCredentialId: 'theSlackToken')`

Importent: The credentials should be Secret Text!!!

2. There is no need to use tokenCredentialId in every slackSend command, you can set it as the general slack token for this Jenkins. over Jenkins -> manage Jenkins -> Configure System, then look for Slack, and enter the right credentials for the token you want to be used. Then you can use:
   `slackSend (channel: '@johnsmith', message: 'hello there', color: '#3eb991'`
3. Using tokenCredentialId in the slack command allows to overwrite the current global token, and like that you can switch between slack apps inside Jenkins.

For more info:
https://plugins.jenkins.io/slack/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).